# DropdownList selectvalue does not seem to change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a dropdown list which is populated on page_load using a linq query.
If I change the value in the dropdown then click a button to run an update query on the record, the original value is still there, if I step through in debug mode I can see the selected value is not changing at all

Here is how Im binding the data to dropdown

```
dlBookingRef.DataSource = d.BookingRef();
dlBookingRef.DataMember = "booking";
dlBookingRef.DataBind();
```

and here is the line in the function which gets the data from the form

```
item.booking_ref = dlBookingRef.SelectedValue;
```

Any idea why it's retaining its original value?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the binding code in `if(!IsPostBack)`, it looks like that in button event as page load gets called due to that your dropdown list gets reset, so bind the dropdown only when page is not posted back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    dlBookingRef.DataSource = d.BookingRef();
    dlBookingRef.DataMember = "booking";
    dlBookingRef.DataBind();
    }
}
```